# @Inject annotation for interface property getting null value in junit

Tags: spring, interface, junit4, spring-annotations, switchyard

I am using `@Inject` annotation for injecting interface(`IFMJobHandler` is an interface) in my class like this

```
@Inject
@Reference
IFMJobHandler jobHandler;
```

While running application with **JUnit** test, `jobHandler` property returning `null` value because of spring annotations for that interface.

Kindly let me know to solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you are trying to run a simple unit test. But in such case there's no Spring Context and nothing is injected. See this link about how to run Spring test - [testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html)